# Sessão expirando no IE

Tags: jsf, jaas

Tenho um sistema em JSF2 onde uso o JAAS para controle de acessos. Está tudo funcionando direitinho no Chrome, mas, pra variar, no IE ocorre um problema.

Basicamente eu tenho um `form` com os campos login e senha:

```
<form action="j_security_check" id="frmLogin" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"/>
  <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"/>
  <p:commandButton id="btLogin" value="Login" onclick="enviar()" icon="ui-icon-play"/>
</form>
```

No Tomcat eu tenho um `jar` que é o meu `loginModule` com as regras de autenticação do login:

```
public class LoginModuleUD implements LoginModule {
...
}
```

WEB.XML

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/sistema/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>teste</description>
        <role-name>usuario</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.ud</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.ud</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>usuario</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Esta é a entidade principal do sistema, ela é injetada em todos as outras entidades:

```
@Named(value="loginMB")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginMB implements Serializable{
    public LoginMB() {
        System.out.println("CONSTRUTOR LOGINMB");
    }
 ...
}
```

Como disse, no Chrome está tudo perfeito, já no IE (testei no 8 e 10), ao acessar um conteúdo protegido ele direciona para a tela de login e ao clicar no botão LOGIN o problema acontece.
Uma hora ele fica perdido e não sai da página de login, outra hora ele vai para a página correta mas perde a sessão (o construtor do LoginMB é acionado novamente) e eu tenho que dar um F5/Refresh na página.

Alguém já se deparou com alguma coisa assim?

Comment: Não me parece ser especificamente problema de sessão. Você chegou a tentar remover toda a "proteção" do sistema e verificar somente a sessão? Para ver se expira nos dois browsers? Se não fez, recomendo fazer, para isolar o problemas. Coloque um tempo de sessão bem baixo, e teste em ambos os browsers.

Comment: Sim, sem a proteção funciona sem problemas. Me parece que o problema ocorre quando o servidor intercepta o fluxo e redireciona para a página de login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que tudo indica, o problema era no form de login, onde o botão LOGIN era um p:commandButton, sendo o comportamento padrão deste componente AJAX=TRUE!

Substitui ele por um

```
<input type="button">
```

e, pelo menos até o momento, tudo funcionando!